# How Can I Keep My Firefox Preferences When Clicking on Javascript Alert?

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, selenium, popupwindow

I am trying to click on a link to download a file.  I have my Firefox preferences set to save the file to a particular location.  However, this particular link provides a popup that I must accept before download.  After I accept the popup, It appears that I lose my preferences, and the file downloads as it normally would (not to the specified file).  How can I avoid losing my preferences?

Here is the site:
http://gtlaw.com/People/Jeffrey-S-Kahn

The link I am trying to hit is this:

```
<a href='javascript:vCard("../webportal/perform.v?obj=ve_oid:poid:Z1tOl9NPl44TqzcSkLMUwG3DtW3D&action=vCard")' style="font-weight: bold;">Download vCard</a>
```

The code I am using is this (modified to make replication a little easier):

```
url = "http://gtlaw.com/People/Jeffrey-S-Kahn"

#set preferences
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
file_name = "C:\..........."
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", file_name)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/x-vcard")
fp.set_preference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 0)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

#get url
driver.get(url)

#get element to click
href = 'javascript:vCard("../webportal/perform.v?obj=ve_oid:poid:Z1tOl9NPl44TqzcSkLMUwG3DtW3D&action=vCard")'
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for e in elements:
    if e.get_attribute("href") == href:
        element = e

#click on element
element.click()

#deal with pop up
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering it's ignoring the never save to disk option, my guess would be the MIME type that you are trying to use.

According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) on vCards, since version 4, they deprecated the type `text/x-vcard`

Try using the MIME type

```
text/vcard
```

If that doesn't work, then you might be able to specify wildcards in the type..

```
*/*
```

Furthermore, your code has room for some extreme optimization. Instead of looping through all those A  elements on the page, just use a CSS selector!

```
driver.find_element_by_css("a[href*='action=vCard']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The code works for most other sites, the problem on this particular site is the javascript alert which appears to drop my firefox settings.  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: that makes no sense at all.. how would a javascript alert clear your settings.. i think you're missing something

Comment: I have played with this quite a bit, any ideas on what I might be missing?